# Combining Two CSV's in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: dataset, data-mining, data, data-cleaning, data-science-model

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

I want to combine both CSV files based on Column1, also when combined each element of Column1 of both csv should match and also each row or Please suggest how to reorder Column1 according to another csv.
In Jupyter Notebook
Thank You!

Comment: please check this out. might help.  [pandas merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below code to merge two file:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv(‘first.csv’)
df2 = pd.read_csv(‘second.csv’)
df = df1.merge(df2, on=‘Column1’)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inner join`:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="Column1", how="inner")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods to connect two different kinds of datasets

---

- Python Pandas - Merging/Joining
- left − A DataFrame object.
- right − Another DataFrame object.
- on − Columns (names) to join on. ...
- left_on − Columns from the left DataFrame to use as keys. ...
- right_on − Columns from the right DataFrame to use as keys. ...
- left_index − If True, use the index (row labels) from the left DataFrame as its join key(s).

---

**Syntax**

`pd.merge(left, right, how='inner', on=None, left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False, sort=True)`

**Answer**

`pd.merge( firstDF, secondDF ,on='Column1')`

> **For More Resources:**  [Padas Data Merging/Joining Resourse](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/python_pandas_merging_joining.htm)